# Switching out the mesh of a game object at runtime

Tags: unity, 3d-meshes

I am trying to switch out the mesh of a game object. I have this script:

```
public GameObject rockPile;
MeshFilter rockMesh;
private string[] rockMeshes = new string[] {"rocks-0", "rocks-25", "rocks-50"};
private int rockIndex = 0;

void Start()
{
   rockMesh = rockPile.GetComponent<MeshFilter>();
}

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) { // click

        rockMesh.sharedMesh = Resources.Load<Mesh>(rockMeshes[rockIndex]); // <-- not working

        if (rockIndex == rockMeshes.Length - 1) {
            rockIndex = 0;
        } else {
            rockIndex++;
        }
    }
}
```

However the mesh isn't changing when I click on the object. The meshes for the rocks are part of imported .fbx files. If I search Assets for the strings I'm using in the `rockMeshes` array, they are there, but they are not the names of the imported fbx files.  I'm not sure the right way to reference the meshes or store them.

File structure:

```
Assets/
├─ 3d/
│  ├─ rockMesh0.fbx  <-- rocks-0 mesh in this file
│  ├─ rockMesh25.fbx  <-- rocks-25 mesh in this file
│  ├─ rockMesh50.fbx  <-- rocks-50 mesh in this file
```

Comment: Resources.Load [is no longer recommended](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/BestPracticeUnderstandingPerformanceInUnity6.html). The recommended way to load assets at runtime is via [Addressables](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/com.unity.addressables.html).

Comment: Also consider the option to convert `rockMeshes` from `string[]` to a `Mesh[]` and assign the meshes via drag&drop in the inspector. That way you avoid the whole "loading resources at runtime" problem alltogether.

Comment: Now that you've corrected the code as I suggested, this example works for me out of the box. My best guess is that you don't have an asset named "rocks-0" in the root of a folder called "Resources", but since you haven't shown us your asset setup I can only speculate about this.

Comment: @DMGregory I added the file structure - as I mentioned in the question I'm not sure the right way to reference the meshes or store them, so would welcome your advice. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you need to re-read the documentation on Resources.Load. See how it requires that the assets to load live under a folder called "Resources"?

Answer (score 1):

I used @Philipp's suggestion and made a public meshes array, assigned those in Unity, and was able to set the mesh using the `sharedMesh` property:

```
public GameObject rockPile;
public MeshFilter[] meshes;
MeshFilter rockMesh;
private int rockIndex = 0;

void Start()
{
    rockMesh = rockPile.GetComponent<MeshFilter>();
}

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) { // click

        rockMesh.sharedMesh = meshes[rockIndex].sharedMesh

        if (rockIndex == meshes.Length - 1) {
            rockIndex = 0;
        } else {
            rockIndex++;
        }
    }
}
```